# Can someone tell me if this a bug in Plone 4.3, in PAM or not a bug at all?

Tags: plone, multilingual

Can someone  tell me WHAT TO DO WITH THIS ISSUE?

Is this a bug in Plone 4.3, in PAM (plone.app.multilingual) or not a bug at all?

In Plone 4.3.14 (4316)
and PAM 2.0.3

Trying to use PAM (plone.app.multilingual 2.0.3)for the first time in Plone 4.3

The "translation options" as well as language selector don`t show up on added content (new page) view option. And that newly created page is in default(canonical?) language in this case English. That happens on every language.
  The whole PAM machinery seems to be out of order on added content items.
Only on language root folder view it is there.("HOME button").
Also the "Media" folder does have the P.A.M options enabled for use.
Here is the screenshot for the language root folder view ("HOME button"):

[image]

And this is of the new content item (a page "Declaration of Principles" added) :

[image]Is something wrong in PAM settings?

If this looks like a bug, are there versions of PLONE 4.3 and PAM that proven to work well together?

Additional info that may help to identify the problem :

If I set the page "Declaration of Principle" To be the default view of the container by changing the setting on "Display > Change content item as default view" then it becomes the "Home" page and PAM machinery comes back on "contents" option but not on "View" option for that page. Same thing on every other installed language...

Comment: I posted your question to our forum, https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-can-someone-tell-me-if-this-a-bug-in-plone-4-3-in-pam-or-not-a-bug-at-all/4760 which is usually the best place to ask for Plone help

Comment: Not sure, but looks like a bug in PAM 2.x to me.  But have you gone into PAM settings and run any migrationy stuff (can't remember exactly what)?

Comment: To Danimal: This is totally new site and instance in local install. Not sure then what do you mean "migration stuff" in this case?  To: T.Kim Nguyen:I appreciate very much your this action!

Comment: Hello, I just tried  to re-run buildout with archetypes enabled in P.A.M and it behaves normally now. Although I am able to see the Babel View of the page but when I click on  create "some language translation" an error happens spelled in the  language chosen:
"We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error… in English option.

Comment: May be since I am just learning to use PAM so may be I need to take some other steps to translate that successfully,or may be it`s a bug. But in general the behavior of not working with only "Dexterity content types" enabled in P.A.M seems to me a buggy behavior. Isn`t it?

Comment: In general, please ask Plone support questions in our forum, community.plone.org where they are likelier to be seen by many.